# Resource entry com.crashlytics.android.build_id is already defined - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

Out of nowhere my Android Studio project started giving me this error: Resource entry com.crashlytics.android.build_id is already defined. I've seen a similar question to mine here on SO, but the solution is not working for me. Every time I try to delete the duplicate entry, it just keeps regenerating on a project rebuild. I could really use any suggestions at this point. Thanks in advance!

Here is the whole error:

C:\Users\Alex\Documents\AppDevelopment\workspace\AsylumLakePreserve\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\workspace\google-play-services_lib\unspecified\res\values\values.xml
Error:(1) Resource entry com.crashlytics.android.build_id is already defined.
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\AppDevelopment\workspace\AsylumLakePreserve\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\com_crashlytics_build_id.xml
Error:(9, 1) Originally defined here.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @yehan in his comment below, these days the issue is most likely causes by not removing fabric decencies/data when upgrading to fire base.

Original:
You've probably already worked around this looking at how old the question is and looking at the error I'm not sure you've got the same issue... but for anyone else stumbling on this one I also ran into something similar whilst updating an old code base from Crashlytics to Fabric and speaking to the Fabric support team they stated that deleting the com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml that was under my app/src/.. directory folder was the correct solution.

Comment: I faced the same issue. But in my case, I had not removed Fabric dependencies while adding Firebase dependencies.